# How to build React Native source and update project

Tags: react-native

I am trying to apply a fix for React Native Navigator transitions: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/3954.

So I manually apply the fix to `BaseViewManager.java` and build the `react-native` repo using `./gradlew`. Then when I run the project using `react-native run-android`, the changes do not seem to be applied.

Is there a step that I am missing? How can I make the changes to the RN source files register in my project?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe try clearing the cache?

Comment: Restarting the packager has no effect. As for the cache, I tried 3 different devices and nothing.

Comment: @RadoMilushev Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to devlop a custom native module and having the same issue. The only workaround I have found is to uninstall the app between updates, which is quite annoying.

Comment: @EggertJóhannesson No, I wasn't able to make it work ... I ended up waiting for the new version of RN which included what I needed. Haven't tried it since ..